# the file was loaded into a wrong encoding problem

Tags: android-studio

So basically, I downloaded a mathparser file and put it in my libs, but when i open the file up it says this: [the file was loaded into a wrong encoding: 'UTF-8'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIEqW.png)

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Cause of this problem, your mathparser the format of the file is UTF-8. Maybe you must changed this file.